# Where are these spaces coming from?

Tags: autocomplete, terminal, tcl

I cant see whats up here...trying to create a simple script to get user input, limited to regular characters only (a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and the -) with tab autocompletion for a defined list of phrases...it works, kinda...

```
#!/usr/local/scripts/packages/bin/expect

set completes { "red one" "blue two" "green three" "four more"  }

proc enableRaw {{channel stdin}} {
   exec /bin/stty raw -echo <@$channel
}

proc disableRaw {{channel stdin}} {
   exec /bin/stty -raw echo <@$channel
}

proc complete { partial } {
  global completes
  set index [lsearch $completes "${partial}*"]
  if { $index != -1 } {
    return [lindex $completes $index]
  } else {
    return $partial
  }
}

enableRaw

set c [read stdin 1]
scan $c %c ascii
set word ""
while {$ascii != 10} {
    switch $ascii {
      9 {
        # TAB
        set word [complete $word]
        puts -nonewline "\n$word"
      }
      127 {A
        # BACKSPACE
        puts -nonewline $c
        set word [string range $word 0 [expr [string length $word] - 2]]
      }
      default {
        switch -regex " $c" {
          " [ a-zA-Z0-9\-]" {
            puts -nonewline $c
            set word "$word$c"
          }
          default {}
        }
      }
    }
    flush stdout
    set c [read stdin 1]
    scan $c %c ascii
}

disableRaw
puts "\n>$word<"
```

But the output is throwing a load of extra spaces that i dont understand where they are coming from!!!

I would expect:

```
bash-3.2$ ./complete_on_tab.exp
red                                    <- tab entered
red one
>red one<
bash-3.2$
```

But i'm seeing:

```
bash-3.2$ ./complete_on_tab.exp
red                                    <- tab entered
   red one                             <- why the indent?
>red one<
bash-3.2$
```

Where are the spaces before the second line coming from??

Comment: I think that, because you're in "raw" mode, you will need to output a carriage return in addition to the newline following the complete.

Comment: d'oh, yes, of course, thank you :-)
works even better if i replace the \n with a \r so now the tab autocompletes on the same line :-D

Comment: @glennjackman do you want to add your comment as an answer?